# SSRS report vertical alignment changes in to horizontal

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, rdl

I have created a report using Visual Studio 2017  and made some of the columns in vertical alignment and uploaded RDL file at reporting services to run the report at work application.

When I run the report at Test environment the report displays the vertical fields into Horizontal, however when I print to view the report vertical text remains the same.

How can I make the report to display the fields that I have designed in vertical?
Any suggestions with the above will be highly appreciated.

[image: Regular Display Mode]

[image: Print Preview mode]

Comment: Note: I have used Rotate 270 for vertical text

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In tablix properties, Make the **Writing Mode** as **Horizontal**.

In a Reporting Services paginated report, you can rotate a text box in different directions:

1.Horizontally

2.Vertically (rotated 90 degrees, with text reading from top to bottom, except East Asian text characters)

3.Rotated by 270 degrees (text reading from bottom to top).

Because you rotate the text box not the text, the rotation applies to all the text in the text box. You cannot specify different directions for parts of the text. Size the column width and the row height manually to accommodate the rotated text.

The WritingMode property, which you use to specify text orientation, isn't in the Text Box Properties dialog box. It's in the Properties pane and set the property there.

[image]

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the input.
The problem still persists.
I have designed the report with 6 columns where three columns are Horizontal and another 3 are vertical. 
When I have uploaded the RDL file into the application to test the vertical text still changing into Horizontal when we view the report in display mode but when we view the same report at Print view mode I can see vertical text boxes displaying the way the report designed.
Do you know why I am viewing the report in Horizontal mode when viewing the report in the regular display but not in print view mode?